# setInterval not updating an integer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a function which displays the amount of milliseconds passed since Midnight of January 1st 1970. I want the integer to update every second/millisecond, however, when I try to use setInterval, it will not update.

```js
var date = new Date()
setInterval(function(){time.innerHTML = date.getTime()}, 1)
```

```html
<span id="time"></span> milliseconds
```

Im pretty sure it is a slight mistake that Im missing out on, but I just cant find the answer.

Comment: Why do you expect `getTime` to yield different results on the _same_ `Date` object? Also, use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setInterval() timer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642176/setinterval-timer-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on user4642212's point about `date` being a fixed time when defined outside the interval, the simple answer would be to create the `new Date()` inside the interval. This can be simplified further though - no need to instantiate a Date just to get its time:

```js
setInterval(() => { time.innerHTML = Date.now(); }, 1);
```

```html
<span id="time"></span> milliseconds
```